# cx_freeze Include independent third-party application

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I want to package my Python application using cx_freeze and include an independent third-party application such that the third-party application's folder is located at the installation directory.

The issue is that cx_freeze does not only copy the folder to the installation directory but also collects the DLLs and copies them again to the `lib` directory. Consequently, the DLLs in the original folder have duplicates in the `lib` folder.

So far, I've tried adding the folder to `options["build_exe"]["include_files"]` which results in the described issue and I've tried ignoring the DLLs by including the third-party application folder to `options["build_exe"]["bin_path_excludes"]` which neither copies the DLLs to the packaged third-party application nor the lib folder.

I was not able to recreate the issue with a minimum working example as I do not know how cx_freeze collects the dependencies, but I included a basic cx_freeze project anyway.

Are there other approaches to include an independent folder in the MSI installer?

**Project structure**

```
.
├── main.py  # just an empty file
├── setup.py
└── third-party-app
    └── mypackage.dll  # just an empty file (I've tried with a nonempty file)
```

**setup.py**

```py
# setup.py

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles = [("third-party-app", "bin")]  # Copy to 'bin' folder

setup(
    name="myproject",
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "include_files": includefiles,
            # "bin_path_excludes": "third-party-app" # using this, the DLL is not included at all
        }
    },
    executables=[
        Executable(
            script="main.py",
            base=None,
        )
    ],
)
```

**Requirements**

```
# requirements.txt
cx-Freeze==6.15.5
```